# (How) can I use the module pattern in Google Apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to put my menu functions inside a module like this:

```
var mainmenuModule = function() {
  return {
    menuItemX: function() {...},
    menuItemY: function() {...}
  };
}();
```

But when I create a menu item, my function is not found:

```
{ name: "X", functionName: "mainMenuModule.menuItemX"}
```

I'm doing this inside a Spreadsheet container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently do this but I see that [Issue 1355](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1355) has been logged as an enhancement to support this for [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries). You can "star" the issue to receive updates.